# How to add Double quotes and comma to a column in R dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe, paste, gsub, double-quotes

I have a dataframe with a single column. I want all values in the column to be wrapped in a double quote and comma like below.

```
df <- data.frame("SN" = 1:4, "Name" = c("John", "Dora","Peter","Lilly"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df$Name
```

When I extract the Name column, I want it `df$Name` as

```
"John",
"Dora",
"Peter",
"Lilly"
```

I tried `paste`, `gsub` and `shQuote` but it doesn't give me the result that I want. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
data.frame(
  SN = 1:4,
  Name = c("John", "Dora", "Peter", "Lilly"),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
) -> xdf
```

`sprintf()`:

```
sprintf('"%s",', xdf$Name)
## [1] "\"John\","  "\"Dora\","  "\"Peter\"," "\"Lilly\","

cat(sprintf('"%s",', xdf$Name), sep="\n")
## "John",
## "Dora",
## "Peter",
## "Lilly",
```

`paste()`:

```
paste('"', xdf$Name, '",', sep = "")
## [1] "\"John\","  "\"Dora\","  "\"Peter\"," "\"Lilly\","

cat(paste('"', xdf$Name, '",', sep = ""), sep="\n")
## "John",
## "Dora",
## "Peter",
## "Lilly",
```

`sub()`:

```
sub("$", '",', sub("^", '"', xdf$Name))
## [1] "\"John\","  "\"Dora\","  "\"Peter\"," "\"Lilly\","

cat(sub("$", '",', sub("^", '"', xdf$Name)), sep="\n")
## "John",
## "Dora",
## "Peter",
## "Lilly",
```

FWIW `sprintf()` wins:

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  sprintf = sprintf('"%s",', xdf$Name),
  paste = paste('"', xdf$Name, '",', sep = ""),
  sub = sub("$", '",', sub("^", '"', xdf$Name))
)
## Unit: microseconds
##     expr    min      lq     mean  median      uq     max neval
##  sprintf 11.705 13.4955 25.91594 19.6095 32.1780 170.989   100
##    paste 13.133 15.3150 34.31982 19.0455 31.9615 340.482   100
##      sub 31.271 34.8555 64.41124 39.8840 78.0180 533.065   100
```

**UPDATE**

I kinda figured you were aiming for:

```
paste0(sprintf('"%s"', xdf$Name), collapse = ", ")
## [1] "\"John\", \"Dora\", \"Peter\", \"Lilly\""

cat(paste0(sprintf('"%s"', xdf$Name), collapse = ", "))
## "John", "Dora", "Peter", "Lilly"
```

Comment: Thanks much. If I have to remove the comma from last value of Name column, how do I do that ?

Comment: I figured you had an actual task at hand. Please add _all_ your requirements and final desired output to the _actual_ question vs get to it piecemeal, but check the update.

Comment: The update you posted gives me values instead of a dataframe with a single column. When I use as.data.frame, its an empty list